# Render a PHP File Via a Another PHP File

Tags: php, class

I want to render a php file through another php file.

I have two php files. One defines a class. Another one holds both html and php. For the sake of better understanding, I am providing a demo code.

`file1.php`

```
<?php

class someClass
{
    public function someMethod()
    {
       echo readfile('file2.php');
    }
}
```

`file2.php`

```
<?php
    $block = 'block';
    echo $block;
?>
<div>djkdjkjkjfkjkdjfkjk</div>
```

`index.php`

```
<?php
require_once 'file1.php'
$class =  new someClass();
$class->someMethod();
```

When I load `www.domain.com`, Output is as follows

```
djkdjkjkjfkjkdjfkjk
71
```

That is my method is not parsing php codes correctly. How can I echo content of `file2.php` in normal way (as we just see the output for `www.domain.com/file2.php`)?

Comment: what's wrong with simply `include 'file2.php`?

Comment: Seems kind off odd to build a class wrapper around a simple include.

Comment: @AleksG : Let me try.

Comment: @MikeBrant : What i have shown is a simple demo. There are lot of complex code behind the scene !

Comment: @AleksG : can you put this as an answer. I had a terrible assumption in my mind that, we can include / require  a pure php file. I am totally unaware of this. My bad. :(

Comment: @programmer_rkt But this demo is at the crux of what you are trying to do.  It seems to me that you are struggling to separate your model from your view. You should not require your class to understand details like file paths to a view files.  This is a very tight coupling in your design which is not necessary.

Comment: @MikeBrant : you are a genius. Yes that is exactly that I am trying to do. seperate logics. That is I am creating my own MVC framework. But actually `file2.php` is not hard coded like that. I have a controller file which is used to set a template file.So whenever that controller processed, it will show the template that is set with that controller. Whether my method is wrong ?

Comment: @programmer_rkt SO in this MVC framework, does your example class in this question represent the model or the controller?

Comment: @MikeBrant : every controller extend from a parent controller. We can set a template file for every child controllers. The method that I have shown above comes inside parent controller. Parent controller has  a protected property that is used to store the template. So when we set a template through child controller, this property is actually setting. Then show that template via parent controller. Does that clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to just

```
include 'file2.php'
```